# Select option from a <select> using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to select an option from an HTML `<select>` object using JavaScript. The select has 6 options and I know I can get the select object using:

```js
document.getElementByID('id');
```

I don't know if that's common, but the options have a property named value, so how can I select an option by value or text?

Comment: Be aware case is important `getElementById` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the options, loop and check the value

```
let select = document.getElementById("id");
for (let i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    if (select.options[i].value == "two") {
        select.selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ghyx623m/

Comment: You should know that this is a duplicate.